# Serialize overriden property with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, datacontractserializer, composite

I have an absract property in the base, that is overriden by 2 derived classes. I want the property to be serialized for one of them, but not the other:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public abstract class Component
{
    public abstract bool IsSelected { get; set; }   
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Leaf : Component
{
    [DataMember]
    public override bool IsSelected { get; set; }   // serialized
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Composite : Component
{
    private List<Component> componentList = new List<Component>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Should *not* be serialized
    /// </summary>
    public override bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (Component component in componentList)
            {
                if (!component.IsSelected)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (Component component in componentList)
                component.IsSelected = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought placing the [DataMember] attribute on Leaf's 'IsSelected' property is sufficient, but apparently, not even the Leaf's property is getting serialized.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you applying both serializable and datacontract?

Answer (score 1):

I dug into this in Reflector, looking at the 4.0.0.0 version of `System.Runtime.Serialization`, and it appears that the code which generates the serialization contract explicitly ignores properties which are overridden from some base class. So the runtime is explicitly and deliberately not serializing `Leaf.IsSelected` in your example.

I suspect it's done this way because they didn't want to deal with checking whether the base class (or some intermediate ancestor class) is also going to serialize the property. If that were the case, you could end up with multiple values of the property being serialized, which is probably undesirable.

As always we should not rely too heavily on what Reflector shows, since the code can always change, but at least we know it's behaving this way on purpose.

If anyone else is looking, the code is the `ImportDataMembers` function in `ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `[DataMember]` attribute on both the **Composite** and **Component** class's **IsSelected** property as well. Try that out.

Comment: But I do not want the Composite to serialize anything!

Comment: Why do you care if Composite.IsSelected is serialized?